# Initializing derived classes through bases

Tags: c++, multiple-inheritance

Consider:

```
struct V {
    V(int i) {
        std::cout << "initialized v" << '\n';
    }
};

struct A {
    A() {
        std::cout << "initialized a" << '\n';
    }
};

struct B : virtual V, virtual A {
    B(int i) :V{i} {
        std::cout << "initialized b" << '\n';
    }
};

class C : virtual V, virtual A {
public:
    C(int i) : V{i} {
        std::cout << "initialized c" << '\n';
    }
};

class D : virtual public B, virtual public C {
public:
    D(int i, int j) :V{i}, B{i}, C{j} {
        std::cout << "initialized d" << '\n';
    }
};
```

If I initialize D in main(), like this:

```
int main() {
    D* d = new D{3,3}; //ok
    B* b = new D{3,3}; //ok
    C* c = new D{3,3}; //undefined
    delete d;
    delete b;
    delete c;

}
```

But if I use a factory, like this:

```
C* factory() {
    return new D{3,3};
}

int main() {
    factory(); //ok
}
```

I can't figure out why it's causing undefined behavior when I initialize D through C in main() but works fine when I use other functions. What's wrong with C? Isn't it just the same as B?

Edit: So my code runs fine on [this demo](http://ideone.com/MZFTms) as I think it should. If there's nothing wrong with my code, is there a problem with my development environment? I'm using the latest mingw-w64 with eclipse CPP.

Comment: How did you detect undefined behavior? Your code appears to compile and run fine ([demo](http://ideone.com/MZFTms)).

Comment: @dasblinkenlight it did compile, but it crashed. It's UB right? I'm really confused about this. I used GCC 4.90.

Comment: @dasblinkenlight: how can you tell it's not UB? Because compiled? Because "it worked" once? That's a very bad heuristic with C++...

Comment: @6502 How did you interpret the question in my comment as a claim that it's not UB?

Comment: I [can't reproduce the claimed crash](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/0ef6d8c58e6fa310), and I also don't see any UB in this code. There are complicated rules governing which derived-to-base conversions can be performed during construction and destruction of an object with multiple inheritance and virtual bases, but this code doesn't do any of that.

Comment: Hmm, I can't reproduce on my mingw GCC 4.9.2 either (I use the distro from http://nuwen.net/).

Comment: @dasblinkenlight: I just wanted to point out that, unfortunately, "compiles and runs fine" isn't a good metric with C++. If you want to say that looking at the code it stands correct and there are no problems with it then fine... saying instead that it's fine because compiles and (apparently) runs without problem is a path to a land of pain with C++ (because there is a lot of code that compiles and "runs fine" that is instead UB).

Comment: Is it possible that the problem is in   `//...` ?

Comment: @Christophe //... is a substitute for deletes, pointless to put here.

Comment: How do you initialize V{i} on D's constructor, if it does not derive V?

Comment: @KuramaYoko yes, but B and C does. The object will not be complete if we don't initialize all bases

Comment: @KuramaYoko that's mandatory because of virtual inheritance of a virtual base class

Comment: @morbidCode the point is that nobody but you can reproduce the error of your code.  But you're the only one using the real content or `//...` .  Could you please compile EXACTLY the same code than in this sample and confirm if the problem is still there ?

Comment: It would help if you reported details about the crash instead of just asserting that you've invoked undefined behaviour.

Comment: @Christophe
 //... is for deleting objects. I have edited the code in the question. That's all the code.

Comment: OK, now you *are* invoking undefined behavior. You are deleting a derived object through a pointer to base with no virtual destructor. Give `V` a `virtual ~V() = default;`.

Comment: @T.C. so that's the problem! Can you post it as an answer?

Comment: Hopefully this has been a valuable lesson in presenting a complete, minimal testcase ... and not arbitrarily replacing code with "...".

Comment: UB includes "seeming to work".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are looking for the undefinedness in all the wrong places.

```
delete b;
delete c;
```

Both lines invoke undefined behavior, by deleting a derived class object (a `D`) through a pointer to base class (a `B*` or `C*`) with no virtual destructor. Give them one (e.g., by adding `virtual ~V() = default;` to `V`), and the crash should disappear.

This is why it's important to verify that the code you post here in fact *reproduces* the crash you are seeing when compiled and run. Someone would probably have spotted the problem in less than 5 minutes if the full code were available at the beginning. Instead, we spent 45 minutes trying to reproduce the problem.